# Telephone voice recording for Android

Tags: android, voice-recording

What would be a FREE application that automatically records all the talks that are done via a smartphone? To local audio files.

Need this because of a reoccuring harassing, need it to have evidence against the harasser (not fun).

Comment: On Android the default telephone program can record it is you tell it to do so. It's just not automatic, though.

Comment: If you're looking for an Automated [Call Recorder](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_various#group_98) (link goes to my list), most of them unfortunately come with tons of trackers. A promising candidate would be [Cube ACR](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.catalinagroup.callrecorder), which promises exactly that: to record each call automatically. Comes a.o. with Facebook and MoPub ads. I haven't tried it myself, so I cannot say if it's worth it. My linked list might have some other interesting candidates.

Comment: @Alejandro: no, I cannot find the "default telephone program can record it" - where exactly is it? Many thanks!

Comment: @SutoTi It's the one you use to normally make calls with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is **Call Recorder - ACR** by NLL.

As a disclaimer, I haven't checked all the current apps that are out there.  However, a few years ago, I did extensive research on this and found that ACR Pro was the best one.  I'm guessing that ACR is probably still the top app because I'm assuming that not many developers would have developed another.

**Google Prevented Such Apps from Working.**  Why won't developers make an app?
Well, ACR and other apps used to work perfectly but then a few years ago, Google made the decision to make such recording apps impossible to work with Android due to their beliefs on privacy.  So, I doubt that any developer have tried to make a program because it's simply too tough to get around Google.  I might be wrong but I haven't heard of an app except ACR that works.

**Be Careful with Privacy Laws in Each State.**  Please look up the relevant law.  In a few states, you can actually go to jail if you secretly record the other party.  It's different with each state.  In other states, it's totally fine.  For example, in California, you cannot do this.  But, in NY and NJ, it's totally fine.  So, check up the laws that pertain to both the state you're calling from *and* the state that the other party is located in.

**Records via Speaker Phone.**  Anyway, as a result of Google's decision, ACR doesn't work as well as before.  What it does now to circumvent Google's decision is it puts a call into speaker mode.  And, then they record the sound coming from your phone's speaker instead of directly copying the data from the call itself.  Google can't prevent this because then it would preclude the recording app on your phone from working.  Just remember that your surrounding environment needs to be quiet or else it will record the outside noise as well.

**Get the Pro version.**  The free version works but I think the pro version has features that are really useful.  For example, the pro version allows you to turn the recording on midway through the conversation.  It's a mere $4 but that isn't much considering.  If you really need it as you say, then $4 won't really matter.  The graphic interace isn't pretty but it gets the job done.  All the others simply don't work anymore.  They will record a file but when you play the file, you will only hear silence.

**Hiccups.**  Many people say that ACR doesn't work for them.  This is due to Google's meddling.  I have a Galaxy Note on which it works though.  You should try to free version.  If it works, get the pro version.  Another suggestion is to install the app via the Galaxy App Store.  If the phone number is in your contacts, it will save the caller's name.  However, the app installed via Google Play won't record the caller's name.  Not a big deal but just another small hiccup.

Please upvote if this helps you!